# Performing Split By Attributes on OBJECTID?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, split-by-attribute

Using ArcGIS Desktop, 10.5.1, I need to "explode" a singlepart polygon FGDB Feature Class into separate FCs.

For example, if the input FC contains 3 polygons, the output will be 3 separate FCs, each containing a single polygon.

I am using the Split By Attributes tool.

How do I split by the input FC's *Objectid* field?

When I open the tool, it does not include the *Objectid* as an allowed Split Field:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution would be to create a new field named ID or something similar. Then Calculate Field and set it equal to OBJECTID, which *does* show up in the field calculator. Then you can use the new ID field as the Split Field in the Split By Attributes tool.

Comment: This works!  FWIW, I find it odd that OBJECTID isn't available "out of the box"...

Comment: Yeah, me too. I've run into this same problem for a few other tools too. Creating a second ID column always seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new field and populate with your OBJECTID values, then split by that field